# how do I access or retrieve the key value of an associative array in laravel / eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I used the query builder to select an item from my DB, now if I do DD ($item) I get an associative array like:

```
array:1 [
  0 => {
    "id": 1,
    "itm_id": 615,
    "itm_val_id": 5,
    "created_at": "2015-10-26 09:42:23",
    "updated_at": "2015-10-26 09:42:23"
  }
]
```

I need to attach the ID to the user in a pivot table, the question is: how do I get that id??

Comment: As its an array of objects you can simply use`{{ $item[0]->id }}`

Answer (score 1):

that doesn't work, but this works:

```
Auth::user()->item()->attach($item[0]->id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `attach` like this:

```
Auth::user()->item()->attach($item[0]->id);

Auth::user()->item()->attach([1 => ['itm_id' => $item[0]->id], $item[0]->id]);
```

You can read more about many to many relation in [Laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#inserting-many-to-many-relationships).

Comment: what's the aim of the second line?

Comment: second line is only an example